# Is there a way to change the output format of the screen recording using terminal?

Tags: macos, catalina, disk-format, screen-recording

I'm using macOS Catlalina 10.15.4 (19E287). I have some screen recording to do and I intend to use the build in screen recording with the screenshot app. 
The problem is I don't want the file to be saved as a .mov I want it to be a .mp4
I know there's a way to change the screenshot format in terminal using 
'''defaults write com.apple.screencapture format'''
Is there something similar to the video option 
Thanks